# parse access token from userID facebook

Tags: access-token, uid

Example: I have Fid my friend is 100001655331013
I want to get this friend's token through his fid, how to do?
Does anyone have a solution that can help me? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

i have code:

```
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
    require_once 'Facebook/Facebook.php';
    require_once 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '1578374648887802',
      'app_secret' => '326222474004cfb11fb5e9dfd09362f4',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
      ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper(); 

    try{
        $response = $fb->get('/100001655331013?fields=id,name,email,gender', 'EAAWbhfxEZBfoBADXwIhBhZAmCOYsSKUGYmlcI2TsZAZCvihO8ewXKWcvCmRVuuuAioLN0JAql4ioacx6dv7nO4Qr4jk96ZC9wdQ0MZAVOSxC25fRqrDd4VKzAEPqJIV0c1EHRxVZB2uouSuLTGpuW2eZApfhgBx65gdnFQrzw6MJJAZDZD');
    } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($graphNode); echo '<pre>';
```

I want to get this person's information including the fields above. But the code only derives name and id. How to get it all.